# springboot app not starting - error (Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext)

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, jetty

I'm having problem while starting restful spring boot app. On seeing the error stacktrace, I could see some exceptions related to jetty.

I could see the below log.

```
Started o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@26586b74{/,file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-docbase.8144885224534920922.8080/,AVAILABLE}
```

I did check `C:/windows/Temp` and I couldn't find `jetty-docbase.8144885224534920922.8080`

It would be great if someone can help me in fixing this issue. How I can create that file so that jetty will identify it?

Below is the complete stack trace.

```
        mo.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler; Started o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@26586b74{/,file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-docbase.8144885224534920922.8080/,AVAILABLE}
morg.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @7364ms
mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformation com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.controllers.ConfigController.buildInformation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildInformationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformationProperties.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
mo.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandle Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@26586b74{/,file:/C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-docbase.8144885224534920922.8080/,UNAVAILABLE}
mo.s.boot.SpringApplication  Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformation com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.controllers.ConfigController.buildInformation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildInformationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformationProperties.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.lewis.web.app.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformation com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.controllers.ConfigController.buildInformation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildInformationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformationProperties.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildInformationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformationProperties.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.lewis.web.app.operations.dashboard.models.BuildInformationProperties.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
```

Many Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}".. Where are you using build.version property? in POM or properties file. Please check it and post your pom/ properties file if you can't solve the issue.

Comment: They are in a property file in classpath. Have added the file and populated the fields as told by @Stanislav. Issue is fixed now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual exception is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in string value "${build.version}"

This means, that Spring application fails create context and to start, because can't create some of the beans because it can not resolve some required autowired variable, in you case it's a `build.version`. You can try to add this variable as command line argument or add it as a property into the `application.properies` file. Or you may locate the bean (it's name is `buildInformationProperties`, where this value should be autowird and try to figure out, why you dont't have it by default.

Comment: Hmm., @Stanislav you are awesome... I just fixed the error. A property file was missing in classpath which contains some build version details. I just added the file and populated the fields. Now, the app is running smoothly with no errors. Great Thanks to you!